# Can I change a permalink of a Wordpress content preview linking to a category instead of the post?

Tags: php, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I'm trying to make a slider in the home with six contents previews. I don't want the previews links to their content, I would want to change their link to some subcategories under a parent. I think changing the permalink to the featured image would be good.

I try to use this tutorial: https://slickmedia.co.uk/blog/wordpress-add-link-featured-image/ 
It works well but not for the preview, it changes the permalink of the featured image in the open content, not in the preview.

A link like this: 
It works well but only for a subcategory, I think I would need a sorting loop to take the subcategories of Articles.

I post the code of the slider from front-page.php

```
  <!-- SLIDES STORIE -->
  <div class="uk-section color-bg-storie">
      <div class="uk-container-large">

          <h2 class="uk-heading-small uk-text-center"><?php bloginfo('name');?>:</h2>

          <div uk-slider="clsActivated: uk-transition-active; autoplay: true;">

              <div class="uk-position-relative uk-visible-toggle uk-light" tabindex="-1">

                  <ul class="uk-slider-items uk-child-width-1-2@s uk-child-width-1-3@m" uk-scrollspy="cls: uk-animation-slide-bottom; target: .uk-padding-large; delay: 300; repeat: true">

                    <?php

                    // La Query
                    $ipp_the_query = new WP_Query( 'category_name=slider&posts_per_page=6' );

                    // Il Loop
                    while ( $ipp_the_query->have_posts() ) :
                      $ipp_the_query->the_post(); ?>

                      <?php $ipp_image_attributes = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'ipp_small' ); ?>


                      <li class="uk-padding-large">
                          <a href="/index.php/category/articoli/paesaggi/">
                            <img src="<?php echo $ipp_image_attributes[0]; ?>" alt="" uk-svg>
                          </a>
                          <div class="uk-position-center uk-panel">
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                              <div><?php the_excerpt(); ?></div>
                            </a>
                          </div>

                      </li>


                    <?php endwhile;
                    // Ripristina Query & Post Data originali
                    wp_reset_query();
                    wp_reset_postdata(); ?>



                  </ul>

                  <a class="uk-position-center-left uk-position-small uk-hidden-hover" href="#" uk-slidenav-previous uk-slider-item="previous"></a>
                  <a class="uk-position-center-right uk-position-small uk-hidden-hover" href="#" uk-slidenav-next uk-slider-item="next"></a>

              </div>

              <ul class="uk-slider-nav uk-dotnav uk-flex-center uk-margin"></ul>

          </div>

      </div>
  </div>
```

I'm searching for a method to link some banner/post preview to a category instead of the open post.

Thanks for all the support!

Comment: You need all your slider images to link to `paesaggi` category?

Comment: Hi! @JotaEle no this is a remedy to give a general link to the slider images. I would give a sub-category link to each image. 

I need a slider with six subcategories preview of the parent Article, I don't find any tutorial about it.

Comment: Uhm, I'm not sure if I fully understand it. Your slider is iterating posts, but you want this post-slides to link to categories. Do you mean a category associated to the post of that slide or the page in which the slider is printed?

Comment: @JotaEle Yes now is iterating post from a category, I was thinking about to create an external link with the content preview directed to subcategories, but it's very difficult for me, because of every post of the slider  should be addressed
to a subcategory of Articles(Articoli).